# Carrying out operations on an unspecified numbers of matrix arguments in python

Tags: python, arguments

How can I extend this function to take an unspecified numbers of matrices A, B (all with the same dimension)?

```
def fun(A, B):
    a = list()
    b = list()

    axis1 = len(A[:, 0])
    axis2 = len(A[0, :])

    for j in range(0, axis2):
        for i in range(0, axis1):
            a.append(A[i, j])
            b.append(B[i, j])

    return a, b
```

Comment: But do you realise `a` is an empty list and does not even qualify for advanced indexing?

Comment: sorry corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically copying items from each parameter array into a new list using the dimensions of the first array. The following exlpoits numpy's slicing to achieve the same result:

```
def func(*args):
    axis1, axis2 = args[0].shape
    return tuple(arr[:axis1, :axis2].flatten().tolist() for arr in args)
```

---

```
A = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
B = np.array([[6,8, 5], [9,0, 3], [2,5,7]])

print(fun(A,B))
# ([1, 3, 2, 4], [6, 9, 8, 0])
print(func(A,B))
# ([1, 3, 2, 4], [6, 9, 8, 0])
```

Comment: This would be the "Pythonic" solution :) A little harder to understand, but probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than send in a fixed number of matrices, send in a list of matrices.  Then, add an additional depth of looping where items are copied from a matrix to the corresponding list.

Also, consider using the `shape` property to get the dimensions of your matrix.

```
def fun(matrices):

    lists = []
    for m in range(len(matrices)):
        lists.append([])

    axis1 = matrices[0].shape[0]
    axis2 = matrices[0].shape[1]

    for j in range(0, axis2):
        for i in range(0, axis1):
            for m in range(len(matrices)):
                lists[m].append(matrices[m][i, j])

    return lists

# usage
A = np.matrix([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
B = np.matrix([[4, 5], [6, 7]])
print(fun([A,B])) # returns [[0, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple arguments (an unknown number) to a function using *args.
Have a look at https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

So you will do something like

```
def fun(*args):
    for arg in args:
        ...
```